# How to One TextBox Value Move to another TextBox unsing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I Have using This Format but i need Correct answer only
This Method used not accurate answer

**JS CODE:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chksa").on('ifChecked',function(event){
    $("#<%=txtSAddress1.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtAddress1.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSAddress2.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtAddress2.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSCity.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSState.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtState.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSCountry.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtCountry.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSPincode.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtPincode.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSEmailID.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtEmailID.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtSContactNo.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtPhoneNo.ClientID%>").val());

    }); 
 <script>
```

Comment: What is `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chksa` control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chksa` to be `checkbox`.

You can use change event and test if checkbox is `checked` copy the values

```
$(function() {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chksa").on('change', function(event) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#<%=txtSAddress1.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtAddress1.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSAddress2.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtAddress2.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSCity.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSState.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtState.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSCountry.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtCountry.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSPincode.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtPincode.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSEmailID.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtEmailID.ClientID%>").val());
            $("#<%=txtSContactNo.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=txtPhoneNo.ClientID%>").val());
        }
    });
});
```